# Light crankset 50/34 road on Claris 8sp group

Tags: road-bike, compatibility, compact-crankset

I want to build a light bike with a limited budget.
I have a Claris group (without crankset) that is fine to me as it's a spare bike, so gearing is not too relevant. Weight is more relevant.
I need a light crankset 50/34 , do you know any 8/9 speed crankset around 700 grams?
Otherwise i would fit a Shimano 105 11speed crankset but I am worried if this will work with 8 speed chain. Anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying product recommendations are off-topic here, so any recommendation will probably be moderated.

But more generally, I'm afraid you are looking for a unicorn/mutually exclusive criteria (weight, budget, 8-speed): 700g matches the weight of current Ultegra 50/34 cranksets, that is only available in 12-speed (or 11-speed if taking the previous generation). If you want a light 8/9 speed crank, the only way would be to search for second hand Ultegra/105 ones, but keep in mind that 8-speed Ultegra is 1990's tech, and you may not even find one with a 50/34 combination and Hollowtech II hasn't been invented. So it's not even guaranteed that it will be lighter than a modern 9-speed one.

You can have a 1-speed mismatch between the crankset and the chain, so a 105 11-speed will be too much of a gap.

I'd think you'd be better off with a modern 9-speed crankset, the weight difference is not that big (960g for a Sora).

Comment: With 90s tech cranksets were actually lighter than modern two-piece ones, because the spindle was part of bottom bracket. Of course the total weight was same or higher, but since when weight weenies made sense?